# C Structs with three options in the magenta kernel

Tags: c, struct, magenta

In the magenta kernel there is a paragraph in which struct got not only a type and name but one option more. I found in the references nothing to explain that syntax. So what is __CPU_ALIGN as argument in struct for and where do I find the syntax for it?

> struct type name ???

```
#if WITH_SMP
/* a global state structure, aligned on cpu cache line to minimize aliasing */
struct mp_state mp __CPU_ALIGN = {
    .hotplug_lock = MUTEX_INITIAL_VALUE(mp.hotplug_lock),
    .ipi_task_lock = SPIN_LOCK_INITIAL_VALUE,
};
```

I know that __CPU_ALIGN itself is used to have aligned bytes for the CPU memory size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a macro shorthand for the [`aligned` attribute](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Common-Type-Attributes.html#Common-Type-Attributes), which is a GCC extension.

The macro is defined as follows:

```
#define __CPU_ALIGN __ALIGNED(CACHE_LINE)
```

The macro __ALIGNED in turn is defined like this:

```
#define __ALIGNED(x) __attribute__((aligned(x)))
```

...which matches the syntax in the GCC documentation. (The value of CACHE_LINE depends on the architecture.)